# Can I has tags in the expanded view of a question in the flags list?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, moderator-tools

Sometimes its nice to see the tags on a question that's in the mod queue.  It can help with understanding where a question is coming from.

When you expand a question in the list, it shows the entire post, but it doesn't show the tags on the post.

I've never seen the need to edit tags from within the mod queue, so that functionality wouldn't be needed.

Comment: I would suggest-edit your 'Can I has tags' in the title, but my change wasn't long enough (6 chars).

Comment: I tried to update the title to "Show tags in expanded view of question in flags list" but I encountered the same problem (as there was only one character that needed changing in the body.)

Comment: Needs mor lolcatz.

Comment: @RobertHarvey since you both have diamonds, will this one work? http://i.imgur.com/PV72U.jpg

Comment: @Will now I see, it was supposed to be some kind of joke :)

Comment: Hey!  Editor!  Leave lolcats alone!

Comment: Not lolcat compliant - [I Can Has Cheezburger?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Can_Has_Cheezburger%3F)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your wish is my whimsy.

(actually this has been there a little while)

Comment: Been meaning to come back and accept...