# Show comments in moderator dashboard when question is expanded

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools

[image: Example of UI changes]

It would help if I could see comments (and [tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/90711/1228)) when evaluating a flag.  Perhaps a lazy-loaded expando shown beneath the question once expanded?

Comment: That'd be cool. Especially if the flag is "more than 20 comments posted".

Comment: There's a fine line here; I'm open to adding things that add context, but eventually you might as well ctrl+click to see the whole post - otherwise we're duplicating everything.... thoughts?

Comment: @MarcGravell: My objective is to reduce the time it takes to act within the mod queue.  ctrl-clicking takes you out of the queue, loads lots of stuff that doesn't matter (in this case, answers), and since we leave the queue to handle the flag, once we close the tab we have to either reload the dashboard or dismiss the flag again to get it out of the queue.

Comment: +1 - I mentioned this when the changes rolled out.  If you can click to see the full post body, I feel that either needs to include the comments or at least the number of comments.  Otherwise, important context could be missed.